# How to create card

Tags: html, css, card

I wanted to create such a card using html and css, but I can't try.  Can anyone help me?  Here are my codes:

```
    <body>
    <div id=“container”>
    <img src=“test.jpeg” />
    <span>title 1</span>
    <span>title 2</span>
    </div>
    </body>
```

Comment: I suggest maybe taking a look at [this](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_cards.asp).

Comment: what do you mean *"such a card"*? such like what? You need to provide a sketch/drawing/image of the desired outcome

Comment: hmm you want to create "such a card" what card? pls explain more

Answer (score -1):

You can create a separate div for the text below your image like this:

```
<body>
    <div id=“container”>
        <img src=“test.jpeg” />
        <div class="inner-div">
            <span>title 1</span>
            <span>title 2</span>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

(I indented the code for clarity)
Further, you can add a border in CSS to your main div to make it look more like a card using the following code:

```
#container{
    border: 1px solid;
}
```